# working and usage of method build(). Please explain or share some link

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using the below method, i did google but no where i found the complete description and usage of  method build(). Please explain or share some link. thank you

@Bean
public NewTopic demoFun(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties)

```
{
    return TopicBuilder.name(kafkaProperties.getdemoFun()).build();
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the builder pattern. It’s a way of constructing objects. `build()` is the last method you call that then returns the main type of object you are trying to construct. Here is a good [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/) on the builder pattern.

Comment: It explained well, Thanks Alexiz

Answer (score 0):

As Robby said it's the builder pattern.

The method `build()` is the last method call to build the object in this case the `NewTopic`.